# Changing the order of the portion in every stack bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the order of each portion in the stack bar chart from the least to the most proportion in each y variable.
This is my data

```
A tibble: 76 x 5
Groups:   Hours.Type [17]
   Hours.Type                           Type.of.Control total  mean  freq
   <chr>                                <chr>           <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Administrative Services Cost Centers City/County        46   9.2  36.8
 2 Administrative Services Cost Centers Investor            9   1.8   7.2
 3 Administrative Services Cost Centers Non-Profit         23   4.6  18.4
 4 Administrative Services Cost Centers State              47   9.4  37.6
 5 Aides & Orderlies                    City/County        46   9.2  20.3
 6 Aides & Orderlies                    District            3   1     1.3
 7 Aides & Orderlies                    Investor           67  13.4  29.5
 8 Aides & Orderlies                    Non-Profit         64  12.8  28.2
 9 Aides & Orderlies                    State              47   9.4  20.7
10 Ambulatory Cost Centers              City/County        52  10.4  14.3
# ... with 66 more rows
```

And this my code to plot the graph.

```
ggplot(null_mean_Type.of.Control_Hours.Type, aes(x = Hours.Type, y = freq, fill = Type.of.Control)) +
  geom_bar(position= position_stack(), stat= "identity", width = 0.7) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(x = Hours.Type ,y = freq, label=paste(freq, sep = " "), group = Type.of.Control), position = position_stack(), hjust = 1.5) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  coord_flip() + #show the proportion of each TOC in every hours type 
  ggtitle("Proportion of T.O.C in every hours type (0 productivity)")
```

the output is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tszk7.png).

I have try to use `reorder` but it end up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOLZJ.png) and it pops out the error of "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)". The warning messages are all like this:

```
1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

The code that I have try reorder is like this:

```
ggplot(null_mean_Type.of.Control_Hours.Type, aes(x = Hours.Type, y = reorder(freq, Type.of.Control), fill = Type.of.Control)) + ...
```

Comment: Unrelated but an empty `facet_grid` does nothing.

Comment: The types of control are ordered alphabetically because that's the default order for factors. What is the order you want? Decreasing? Then try `reorder(freq, -Type.of.Control)` with a minus sign.

Comment: add a minus sign doesn't plot a graph

Comment: What output you are looking for? How do you want to reorder the bars?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention about it. I would like to change the order from the least to the most proportion in each y variable.